# Get reference to a antd time picker and store its value to state variable

Tags: reactjs, antd, timepicker, ant-design-pro

I need to get the value that user selected in the time picker to store in a state. In the antd timepicker document I couldn't a reference parameter.

**Code:**

```
const format = "HH:mm";

export default function MyTimePicker() {
  const [mytime, setTime] = useState("00:00");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTime(e.targe.value);
    console.log(mytime);
  };

  return (
    <TimePicker
      defaultValue={moment("12:08", format)}
      format={format}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
}
```

It shows

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

The Docs does only have onSelect and onChange but how to get the selected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onOk` when you need to update state only when user click Ok button. Otherwise use `onChange` or `onSelect`

```js
  const [timeString, setTimeString] = useState('');

  return (
    <TimePicker
      onOk={(time) => {
        setTimeString(timeString);
        console.log(time);
        console.log(timeString);
      }}
    />
  );
```

In docs https://ant.design/components/time-picker/ looks like `onOk` is not presented but you can find `onOk` description here https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker

When u use `onChange` you should use `handle` function with parameters: `(time, timeString)`

Comment: Prefect ! Thanks

Comment: What all are there other than time, timeString ? Because using time or timeString for just the time entered and to store them in a state in format of ("0222" -->02:22) take a lot of code

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas you can use any format what you want via `time.format(format)`. Example https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-qqe5k?file=/index.js:344-363

Comment: Try the same with RangePicker fails. It says `time.format is not a function`

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas RangePicker doesn't provide one `time` as a parameter. RangePicker works with two dates, so `onChange` signature its `function(dates: [moment, moment], dateStrings: [string, string])` where first parameter `dates` its array of date from and date to.